# Simulate post form submit with a function call with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

With jQuery, we can simulate submitting a form:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input name="key1" value="value1" />
    <input name="key2" value="value2" />
</form>
```

With an AJAX function call:

```
$.post('', { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, function() {
   // do call back
});
```

If we use `jquery.form.js`

```
$('#form1').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function() {
        // do call back
    }
});
```

---

#### Ok, now comes my question:

I don't have the form in the markup and I want to submit a form with some dynamic content using the method 'POST'.

I want to make a function call to simulate the procedure, maybe something like:

```
utils.post('/url', {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'});
```

After that call, the effect is just the same as the form I have above and I submit it, with a natural synchronized way.

Is there a nice way to do this?

---

If the problem is not clear, I can make an ugly example to explain what I want:

```
util.post = function(url, fields) {
    var $form = $('<form action="'+url+'" method="post"></form>');
    var key, val;
    for(key in fields) {
        if(fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            val = fields[key];
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+val+'" />');
        }
    }
    $form.submit();
}
```

The above method works but I think it is not nice enough. When the fields have a special character or something else it may cause an error.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just call `$.post()` with that URL and data.

Comment: @Barmar I just want to submit the form in a natural way, not using xhr.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a natural way"?

Comment: @TylerH The effect is just the same as if I submit a normal form, clicking the submit button.

Comment: That is the POST method. XMLHttpRequest is the same thing.

Comment: @TylerH No, it is not the same thing. Imagine a backend returns a 302 after the process, with AJAX(XHR) browser will follow the redirect and then return the final result to javascript. While with HTML form post, the browser itself will actually be redirected to the new location. Correct me if I'm wrong, there is no way to stop the request half-way and actually redirects the client in the AJAX case, plus you might run into CORS issue.

Comment: @zypA13510 yes it is the same thing; XHR uses a POST request to submit data.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure if you actually read my comment about how XHR and native form post handles the **_same_** request differently.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use jQuery to construct the form functionally, rather than by concatenating strings, so special characters won't be a problem.

You will need to attach this form to the HTML `body` before submitting it; recent versions of Chrome [now require this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/962c2a22ddc474255c776aefc7abeba00edc7470%5E!/).

```
var util = {};
util.post = function(url, fields) {
    var $form = $('<form>', {
        action: url,
        method: 'post'
    });
    $.each(fields, function(key, val) {
         $('<input>').attr({
             type: "hidden",
             name: key,
             value: val
         }).appendTo($form);
    });
    $form.appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you master. By the way, do you think it is a good practice to do so? I want to add this function to my toolkit functions and use it widely.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use something like this. I do highly recommend this method of creating DOM elements, rather than constructing HTML strings.

Comment: There is a problem with the code. In ```append``` function, there shoud be  ```$('<input>', {...})```

Comment: This now fails in Google Chrome with a `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected`

Comment: Append the form to the body. `$form.appendTo('body').submit()`

Answer (score 7):

Since the accepted answer may no longer work in e.g. [Chromium based browsers](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/962c2a22ddc474255c776aefc7abeba00edc7470%5E!/) in some circumstances, here's a workaround:

```
util.post = function(url, fields) {
  var $form = $('<form>', {
    action: url,
    method: 'post'
  }).append(
    $.map(fields, function(key, val) {
      return $('<input>').attr({
         type: "hidden",
         name: key,
         value: val
      }).appendTo($form);
    })
  )
  var w = window.open("about:blank")
  w.document.write($form[0].outerHTML)
  w.document.forms[0].submit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is that since you don't have form fields to get data from you can't use .serialize to build the array. You just have to build the array manually.

Key1...Keyn can be names you assign instead of form fields name attributes (that is what actually serialize do) and values can be whatever you want:

- html from a div;
- values calculated by you;
- javascript variables;
- values coming from db;

The point is that you are not simulating posting a form in any case. With ajax you are just **making it asyncronous** and this helps you because you don't need to change/reload the page to elaborate the form results.